# Problem getting Angular JS data into Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have data like this, {{}} can't be read in Javascript

```
<textarea id="commentid" name="commentid" onclick="myFunction2()"></textarea>
<input type="image" id="{{data.number}}" ng-src="{{'<?= $actual_link ?>' + iconsend}}" alt="Submit" disabled>
<script>
  function myFunction2() {
    $("textarea").keyup(function() {
      var value = document.getElementById('commentid').value;
      if (value === '') {
        document.getElementById("{{data.number}}").disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("{{data.number}}").disabled = false;
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```

Calling an Angular JS function in Javascript

[Image Error](https://images4.imagebam.com/07/1e/06/MEO45H3_o.png)

Comment: `document.getElementById("{{data.number}}").disabled = true;` is not possible in plain javascript. You should at least put this logic in your AngularJs controller, or better yet, use native AngularJs directives to achieve disabling the input fields. E.g. look at [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) and [ng-keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup)

Comment: It's default there, what if we flip it from closed to open? @Jeppe

Comment: I have no idea what that means. You need to be a lot more specific in your question